# Not getting browse option in Fileinput in R shiny

Tags: r, file-io, shiny

When I run the code below to get the files from the user using fileinput in R shiny, I don't see the browse option in the output. Please take a look at the code and rectify it. TIA. Do not read beyond this. SO is not posting this question until I write some more words, so I'm typing these lines. Never mind.

UI

```
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
             titlePanel("Uploading Files"),

               # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
                sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("type2","Select the input type:",c("File"="f","Dataset"="ds1","URL"="url2")),

      conditionalPanel(condition="input.type==\"f\"",
                       fileInput("fi", "Choose CSV File",
                                 accept = c(
                                   "text/csv",
                                   "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                   ".csv")
                       ),
                       tags$hr(),
                       checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
                       radioButtons("sep", "Separator",
                                    choices = c(Comma = ",",
                                                Semicolon = ";",
                                                Tab = "\t"),
                                    selected = ","),
                       radioButtons("quote", "Quote",
                                    choices = c(None = "",
                                                "Double Quote" = '"',
                                                "Single Quote" = "'"),
                                    selected = '"')))
```

server

```
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
                 y <- reactive({
                     b<- switch(input$type2,
               f=
                 if(is.null(input$fi))     return(NULL) else
                   read.csv(input$fi$datapath,
                            header = input$header,
                            sep = input$sep,
                            quote = input$quote),
               ds1=get(input$ds2, "package:datasets"),
               url2= if(is.null(input$url3))     return(NULL) else
                 read.csv(url(input$url3))
    )

    if(input$disp == "head") {
      return(head(b))
    }
    else {
      return(b)
    }
  })
```

Comment: `condition="input.type2==\"f\""` ?

Comment: Thank you so much Stephane. means a lot